# Finite Expectation implies X is finite proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I was wondering if my proof was satisfactory to prove:
\begin{equation}
     \text{If } X\geq0 \text{ and } \mathbb{E}(X)<\infty, \text{ then } \mathbb{P}(X<\infty) = 1
\end{equation}
My proof:
For contradiction, suppose $\mathbb{P}(X< \infty) = 0$, then
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P}(X = \infty) = c
\end{equation}
for some $c \in (0,1]$ and
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{x\in X(\omega)} x\mathbb{P}(X=x) = \left( \sum_{x\in X(\omega)\setminus k} \mathbb{P}(X=x) \right) + k\mathbb{P}(X=k) = \infty
\end{equation}
as $k \to \infty$
hence contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works only for discrete random variables. But it is not given that $X$ is discrete.

In the general case use integrals: If  $P(X=\infty)>0$ then $EX \geq EXI_{X=\infty} =E(\infty I_{X=\infty})=\infty$.